accidentally deleted /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
I'm using fresh 24.04 ubuntu and accidentally deleted /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf  sudo update-initramfs -u haven't run yet, is it possible to restore it? or can someone share this default file to me? just copy-paste it here

did you check your wastebasket?

it was sudo rm, so no

you might find this resource  and also this one helpful

it will not help me to recover this file, I just need someone with 24.04 to share this file with me

given up before you try then? How about re-installing the OS if it's that urgent.

The file can be found in the kmod package, however the contents will vary depending on your install. You mention the release (24.04) but not which product (Server? Desktop? flavor?), your architecture?  as your install media can install different kernels (GA, HWE, OEM) plus your hardware (and changes made post-install) can cause the contents of that file to be non-standard as kernel modules will be specific to details you've not mentioned. To restore the file you'll need to ask whomever setup your backup strategy.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/kmod

The file is not essential. If your system boots without it, you don't need it. It simply lists blacklisted modules, and is commonly empty.

unfortunately, I have no backup strategy, I'm using ubuntu 24.04 desktop, with all defaults, ryzen 7 4800h on a laptop. I saw some lines that just increases stability of system

# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac

found this data, looks correct for me
